# What is the best way to generate Certificate Signing Request using AndroidKeyStoreProvider?

Tags: java, android, certificate, keystore, csr

I read [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html).

It says how to generate a `KeyPair`, however it doesn't specify how to generate a Certificate Signing Request based on the generated keys.

From my research, to generate a CSR in Java, the samples from the web usually use the package `sun.*` or the BouncyCastle library. It seems like there isn't a way to generate a CSR with the standard `java.security` API. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13639514/possible-to-generate-csr-using-java-security-without-sun-packages-or-external-li) and it seems to say the same thing.

Do I have no choice but to use BouncyCastle? It is hard to imagine that Android Developers don't consider this kind of usage.

By the way, the article also mentions that:

> Generating a new PrivateKey requires that you also  specify the
> initial X.509 attributes that the self-signed certificate  will have.
> You can replace the certificate at a later time with a certificate
> signed by a Certificate Authority

Suppose I finally get a certificate signed by a Certificate Authority. What exactly should I do to "replace the certificate at a later time"?

Comment: hello! have you found a solution? I would appreciate if you shared materials how to generate CSR without Bouncy/SpongyCastle

Answer (score 5):

The best way to create a CSR on Android is to use [SpongyCastle](https://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/), which is an implementation of [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) for Android. SpongyCastle already does a lot of the heavy-lifting for you so it will make your life much easier.

---

My implementation is heavily based on the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37898553/7487335), but uses the Android KeyStore for security and SpongyCastle's `JcaContentSignerBuilder()` instead of the custom `ContentSigner`.

### Add SpongyCastle to your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.51.0.0'
compile 'com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:1.51.0.0'
```

### Create the KeyPair in the [Android KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore):

```java
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore"); // store the key in the Android KeyStore for security purposes
keyGen.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                  "key1",
                  KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
                  .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                  .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                                KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA384,
                                KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                  .build()); // defaults to RSA 2048
KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
```

### Create the CSR using said KeyPair:

```java
private final static String CN_PATTERN = "CN=%s, O=Aralink, OU=OrgUnit";

//Create the certificate signing request (CSR) from private and public keys
public static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateCSR(KeyPair keyPair, String cn) throws IOException, OperatorCreationException {
        String principal = String.format(CN_PATTERN, cn);

        ContentSigner signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(DEFAULT_RSA_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM).build(keyPair.getPrivate());

        PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder csrBuilder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
                new X500Name(principal), keyPair.getPublic());
        ExtensionsGenerator extensionsGenerator = new ExtensionsGenerator();
        extensionsGenerator.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(
                true));
        csrBuilder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest,
                extensionsGenerator.generate());
        PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = csrBuilder.build(signer);

        return csr;
    }
}
```

And that's it, now you have a `PKCS10CertificationRequest` that you can send to your server.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding generating a CSR (certificate sign request) on the android phone, I think it is rather straightforward to use [Spongycastle](http://rtyley.github.io/spongycastle/) instead. It is an android port of Bouncycastle.

> Suppose I finally get certificate signed by a Certificate Authority.
>   What exactly should I do to "replace the certificate at a later time"?

Once you have the actual signed certificate which you are supposed to get from the CA (Certificate Authority), you no longer need your CSR; you should just store the signed certificate on the phone. Where to save them - I guess you can get help [here](http://nelenkov.blogspot.jp/2011/11/ics-credential-storage-implementation.html).