# How do you create a Certificate Signing Request using the KeyStore on Android?

Tags: java, android, ssl, ssl-certificate, pkcs#10

I'm generating a SSL KeyPair in an Android app using the [`KeyStore`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) API. I want to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) from the Public/Private key pair so that it can be sent to an external CA for signing.

Is this possible?  I'd like to use the builtin Android libraries rather than BouncyCastle if possible, in order to have Android store the keys securely.

Comment: have you found a solution using BouncyCaslte (without SpongyCastle)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use BouncyCastle and java.security.KeyStore together. I had to create the key pair using the Android libraries, then manually build the certificate structure in BouncyCastle. The resulting CSR could be exported and externally signed then the certificate imported back to the Android KeyStore using keyStore.setCertificateEntry()

Comment: I am able to construct CSR using SpongyCastle, but I need it to be done without SC library. Can you please share how to build CSR using BouncyCastle? Or how can I contact you with email, if possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the certificate enrollment process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850134/what-is-the-certificate-enrollment-process)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to generate Certificate Signing Request using AndroidKeyStoreProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907326/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-certificate-signing-request-using-androidkeysto)

Answer (score 2):

[Certificate enrollment process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850134/certificate-enrollment-process)

Check this link. It generate key pair and CSR.
Regarding generating a CSR (certificate sign request) on the android phone, I think it is rather straightforward to use Spongycastle instead. It is an android port of Bouncycastle.

Comment: Well, I'm also looking for the creation CSR on android. Could you give me the example or link to refer?

Comment: The post you linked to doesn't mention how to use the Android `KeyStore` API at all and instead generates the keys in memory, which is insecure in comparison to the `KeyStore`.

Comment: Hi @JoshCorreia, Have you found any solution to generate CSR using KeyStore

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bouncy Castle to work with the keys from Android KeyStore.
This doesn’t mean that you have to set the Bouncy Castle as a security provider. It is enough to include the library:

```
implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:1.72'
```

Note: Spongy Castle is obsolete. Standard Bouncy Castle library has to be included in your Android application.  For details on why see: https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/issues/34

```
val keyPairGenerator: KeyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
    KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_EC,
    "AndroidKeyStore"
)
val keySpecBuilder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
    Constants.clientCertificateKeyAlias,
    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY
).setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_NONE, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
keyPairGenerator.initialize(keySpecBuilder.build())
val pair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair()

val p10Builder: PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder = JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
    X500Principal("CN=My Client Certificate"), pair.public
)
val csBuilder = JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withECDSA")
val signer: ContentSigner = csBuilder.build(pair.private)
val csr: PKCS10CertificationRequest = p10Builder.build(signer)

val pemObject = PemObject("CERTIFICATE REQUEST", csr.encoded)
val csrAsString = csrAsStringingWriter()
val pemWriter = PEMWriter(csrAsString)
pemWriter.writeObject(pemObject)
pemWriter.close()
csrAsString.close()
Log.v("CSR", "CSR: $csrAsString")
```

Answer (score -1):

Since Android apps are built with Java, you can use the Java `keytool` tool to generate a CSR: [Request a Signed Certificate from a CA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html#sthref130).