# Generate CSR from private key or Key Store

Tags: android, keystore, private-key, public-key, csr

How can i generate CSR from the Key Store.

I have generated CSR from key pair. Below is my code.

```
public static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateCSR(KeyPair keyPair, String cn) throws IOException,
        OperatorCreationException {
    String principal = String.format(CN_PATTERN, cn);

    ContentSigner signer = new JCESigner (keyPair.getPrivate(),DEFAULT_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);

    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder csrBuilder = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
            new X500Name(principal), keyPair.getPublic());
    ExtensionsGenerator extensionsGenerator = new ExtensionsGenerator();
    extensionsGenerator.addExtension(Extension.basicConstraints, true, new BasicConstraints(
            true));
    csrBuilder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest,
            extensionsGenerator.generate());
    Log.e("csr builder ","csr "+csrBuilder.toString());
    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = csrBuilder.build(signer);

    return csr;
}
```

But i cannot generate CSR from Keystore(Private Key).
Is there any way i can generate key pair from Keystore?

Please help me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to generate Certificate Signing Request using AndroidKeyStoreProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907326/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-certificate-signing-request-using-androidkeysto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is compatible with Android KeyStore. You just need to generate the `KeyPair` into the `Keystore`

The KeyStore is available from Android 4.3 (API level 18). There are slight differences between versions

**Android >=18 < 23**

```
KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                .setAlias(alias)
                .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias + ", O=Android Authority"))
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                .build();

KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");

kpg.initialize(spec);
KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

**Android >=23**

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(
                KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");


kpg.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                alias,
                KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                .build());

KeyPair keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

Comment: Hi pedrofb , the problem is that i only have the private key, is  it possible to generate CSR just from the private key not with the Key pair.

Comment: No, it is not possible. The CSR must include the public key which is embedded later in the X509Certificate built and signed by your CA. But, I do not understand, a private key is linked with a public key, so if you have the private, you also should have the public

Comment: Actually pedrofb i am generating key pair in Smart card. But due to the security reason i cannot get the key pair value. I only see the Keystore from which i generate the key (KeyStore store = null;store =  GPKIKeyStore.getInstance();
         store.load(null /* stream unused */, null /* password unused */);   
         aliases = store.aliases();) . Then i generate Key( Key key = store.getKey(alias, null);)  So this only conatin the private key.

Comment: Is there any way i can get the keypair value from the Keystore?

Comment: The KeyPair is not, but the `java.security.KeyStore` have the private key and the public key you need. Use `PublicKey publicKey = store.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey()`

Comment: But Pedrofb i don't have any certificate. So there will be no public key.

Comment: The smartcard should contain the public key in a certificate. How you are connecting to the smart card from android? Will it be through NFC? Surely this manufacturer will be documented in the driver

Comment: I am connecting a smart card with the Bluetooth device and they doesn't deal with CSR only generating key pair in smart card.

Comment: Ok, I thought you were using a smartcard with a pre built certificate. Then, when you generates the keypair, it should be a way to recover the public key. If not, the cryptographic operation does not make sense. Also, I think my answer does not fit your use case, because you said 'Android' and 'KeyStore' that is the name of Android Keystore System https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're talking about `java.security.KeyStore`. This abstraction requires that each stored `PrivateKey` has a corresponding chain of `Certificate` instances (one or more certificate). This means you should be able to create a `KeyPair` from a private key entry of `KeyStore`. For example, if the private key is stored under "test":

```
String alias = "test";
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(...);
keyStore.load(...;);
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(alias, null);
PublicKey publicKey = keyStore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();
KeyPair keyPair = new KeyPair(publicKey, privateKey);
generateCsr(keyPair, ...);
```